# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "location=\.php5" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:92

Tags: php, apache, nginx, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have installed nginx, apache2 and php.

Then I edited the config for the `domains` to use. Then Ii tried restarting nginx but it did not work, and I got

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I have tried `systemctl status nginx.service` and got:

```
â— nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-07-15 15:01:30 CEST; 1min 29s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 1349 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 15 15:01:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jul 15 15:01:30 raspberrypi nginx[1349]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "location=\.php5" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:92
Jul 15 15:01:30 raspberrypi nginx[1349]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 15 15:01:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 15 15:01:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 15 15:01:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Actually I haven't tried anything because I have no idea of what I am doing, so please help.

Comment: You should add the config you are using, highlighting the changes you have made, and use the formatting tools to make it al readable.

Comment: The statement `location=\.php5` is clearly invalid. What are you trying to achieve with it? If you are attempting to match URIs ending with `.php5` then you should be using `location ~ \.php5$` (and note that there are two spaces in that expression).

Comment: i am trying to host a website for me to control the gpios of my raspberry. i got the php ready [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAMLwbShFFQ). i followed this tutorial but when i opened the pinoff.php it got interpreted as html. Maybe there is another solution to solve that than nginx?